PHP multiple checkbox save values in array like i clicked them
Hello i use a code that i found here but i have a problem.
The problem is that the result of all checkboxes are a sorted one. But i want that the sort is like i clicked them.
Like a Android Code Pattern, like 6-9-8-7 but the code only gives me 6-7-8-9
Can you help me?
<form method='post' id='userform' action='test.php'> <tr>

    <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='1'>1
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='2'>2
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='3'>3<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='4'>4
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='5'>5
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='6'>6<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='7'>7
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='8'>8
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='9'>9<br>
    </td> </tr> </table> <input type='submit' class='buttons'> </form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['checkboxvar'])) 
{
    print_r($_POST['checkboxvar']); 
}
?>



HTML by itself wouldn't have this information.  You'd probably need to maintain your data in JavaScript as the user clicks and use that data to populate a hidden form field.

The values from the checkboxes (and any other fields) in your form are posted in the $_POST in the order they appear in your HTML. You would have to use something like javascript to record the order the checkboxes are clicked into for example another hidden field to capture it, which will become complex if the user then changes and unchecks the box midway through etc.

Storing checkbox values in order that they are clicked in PHP, Javascript checkbox selection order

fyi, <form> is not a valid parent for <tr>

You have to use javascript/jQuery here.
Below code might help you to understand.
<form method="post" id="userform" action="">
    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='checkbox' class="checkbox" value='1'>1<br>
                <input type='checkbox' class="checkbox" value='2'>2<br>
                <input type='checkbox' class="checkbox" value='3'>3<br>
                <input type='checkbox' class="checkbox" value='4'>4<br>
                <input type='checkbox' class="checkbox" value='5'>5<br>
                <input type='checkbox' class="checkbox" value='6'>6<br>
                <input type='checkbox' class="checkbox" value='7'>7<br>
                <input type='checkbox' class="checkbox" value='8'>8<br>
                <input type='checkbox' class="checkbox" value='9'>9<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    
    <input type="hidden" name="checkboxvar" id="checkboxvar">
    <input type='submit' class='buttons' value='Submit'>
</form>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['checkboxvar']) && !empty($_POST['checkboxvar'])) {
    echo "<h3>Selected Values:</h3>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['checkboxvar']);
} else {
    echo "<h3>No checkboxes selected.</h3>";
}
?>
    <script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
    const hiddenInput = document.getElementById('checkboxvar');

    let selectedValues = [];

    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                selectedValues.push(this.value);
            } else {
                selectedValues = selectedValues.filter(value => value !== this.value);
            }
            hiddenInput.value = selectedValues.join(',');
        });
    });
});
</script>

